# simple animation using an array of images

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

So this is what I did: I populated the nib with an image view and a round rect button. When the round rect button is pressed, a simple animation is shown using an array of images...code I used to do this looks like this:

```
imageview.animationImages = images;
```

and...

```
[imageview startAnimating];
```

and then...

```
[self.view addSubview:imageview];
```

But the issue is after I added the subview, the superview is though not visible but its still there, so even though the button is not visible it still can be pressed to fire the animation once again. How do I disable this button after the animation is fired. I hope you understood me.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using an `IBAction` with a `sender` parameter. At the end of this method do

```
UIButton *temp = (UIButton *) sender
temp.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: yeah I am using the function `-(IBAction)btnclicked:(id)sender;` and I did try what you said but it is throwing an exception saying "Property 'enabled' not found on object of type 'id'". What exactly do you expect `sender.enabled = NO;` to do? What is the 'sender' parameter actually meant for? Shouldn't it work fine with our this parameter? BtW whats the difference between an exception and an error?

Comment: That's a lot of questions... but right you need to cast `sender` to a `UIButton`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: So here you created an instance of UIButton class named temp and assigned the parameter sender to it? And then you disabled it. Though it makes the button not work while the animation is going on but this makes the button dead and I can't use it again.

Comment: Actually in objective-c the `*` means that a variable is a pointer. So I just made a pointer to the `UIButton` that was triggering your action and then passed a message to the selector `setEnabled:` telling the button that it was disabled. `sender` is passed to the method as type `id` which doesn't have the property `enabled`, so you have to cast sender to a `UIButton` (basically promise to the compiler that whatever triggers the event will be a button). If you want to re-enable the button later, then you could try using an `NSTimer`.

Comment: okay so you mean i should use `NSTimer` to keep the button disabled for the same duration as i am using for the animation? But it won't be very elegant way to do it right? thx for helping btw.

Comment: If you want it to be disabled for a certain amount of time, there are only a couple ways to do it. If you have some way of observing when your animation completes you could also store the reference to the `UIButton` somewhere and then enable it. Elegant/inelegant isn't really a big deal for such simple code.

Comment: I see...I am doing that...there is another little thing I am stuck at: when i run the animation for the first time after the simulator opens...the animation does not synchronize with the sound but after using it once when I press the button again it does. Any idea why?

Comment: Make another question; comments aren't really meant for this purpose.

Comment: @SahilChaudhary and please grab a good iOS development tutorial NOW, read it and **do make the effort understanding it**. This is far too basic to be asked on SO. You don't even know what a typecast or properties are...

Comment: old question, asked that probably three months ago